# Else without If Compilation Error

Tags: excel, if-statement, compiler-errors, excel-2007, vba

I'm not sure why this is throwing a compile error and telling me that I have an Else Without If.  The error is on ElseIf lines.  Everything else seems to be working.  Any suggestions?

```
If IsEmpty(Me.ComboBox15.Value) = False Then
    strFind = Me.ComboBox15.Value    'what to look for
    With Ws.Range("cGroup")  'where to look
    Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ComboBox15.Value
    Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
        'c.Select
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            With Me
                .ComboBox15.Value = c.Offset(0, 0).Value
                .ComboBox16.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .ComboBox17.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
                .ComboBox1.Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
                .ComboBox19.Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
                r = c.Row
                f = 0
            End With
            FirstAddress = c.Address
        Else: MsgBox strFind & "Not listed"    'search failed
        End If
ElseIf IsEmpty(Me.ComboBox16.Value) = False Then
    strFind = Me.ComboBox16.Value    'what to look for
        With Ws.Range("cGeography")  'where to look
        Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2,  Criteria1:=ComboBox16.Value
        Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
            'c.Select
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                With Me
                    .ComboBox15.Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    .ComboBox16.Value = c.Offset(0, 0).Value
                    .ComboBox17.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    .ComboBox1.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    r = c.Row
                    f = 0
                End With
                FirstAddress = c.Address
            Else: MsgBox strFind & "Not listed"    'search failed
            End If
        End With
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Me.ComboBox17.Value) Then
            strFind = Me.ComboBox17.Value    'what to look for
            With Ws.Range("cDept")  'where to look
            Sheet2.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ComboBox17.Value
            Set c = .Find(strFind, LookIn:=xlValues)
                'c.Select
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    With Me
                        .ComboBox15.Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value
                        .ComboBox16.Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
                        .ComboBox17.Value = c.Offset(0, 0).Value
                        .ComboBox1.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        r = c.Row
                        f = 0
                    End With
                    FirstAddress = c.Address
                Else: MsgBox strFind & "Not listed"    'search failed
                End If
            End With


Else: MsgBox "Error"
End If
```

I apologize for any formatting/indentation errors.  I'm brand new to VBA.  I searched for the answer, but everything I was finding looked like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `With` block:

```
With Ws.Range("cGroup")  'where to look
```

is never ended within the `If` block that it is placed in.

Comment: That End If should be closing the block that begins with   If Not c Is Nothing Then                  (Sorry, I can't figure out how to format this).  I tried removing it just in case, but I still get the same error.  @Soren

Comment: You are right. That wasn't it. I have updated my answer.